# WPF - MenuItem icon shows partially

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a simple `MenuItem` with `Icon`, without `Header`. Icon height and width must be equal to the menu item's dimensions. Icon size - 48x48. My XAML:

```
<Menu>
        <Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <MenuItem Width="48">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="../Images/sync-48.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

But it looks like this:

[image: this]

When I am trying to set width and height manually - like this:

[image: this]

The only way I found is setting a negative margin. How can I make the menu icon show correctly?

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by show "correctly". Could you clarify what you want to see?

Comment: Try setting the width of the Image element

Comment: like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/243hn.png)

Comment: I tryied to set Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=AddItem}", where AddItem is menuitem, but nothing changed

Comment: Try StretchDirection="Both"

Comment: Set image width and height, not menuitem

Comment: Finally, Image StretchDirection="Both", Width="48" and Height="48" looks like second picture

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<MenuItem>
  <MenuItem.Header>
     <StackPanel>
        <Image Width="48" Height="48" Source="Image.png" />                   
     </StackPanel>
  </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

?